SSAS Tabular Model Refresh Time Increased After Redeployment
I recently redeployed one of my SSAS tabular models to my production environment due to incorrect calculations. However, after the redeployment by taking the model from git, the refresh calculation step has gone from taking 30 minutes to over 1 hour and 30 minutes.
The exact same setup in my test environment still runs as quickly as before. Additionally, other steps, like processing the model, take the same amount of time as it did before which if good.
I can't figure out what might be causing this significant increase in refresh calculation time in production.
What factors could lead to this discrepancy, and how can I troubleshoot or resolve it?

I note that you haven't responded to, nor accepted any answer to you previous questions - any reason for that?

Nope no excuses. Most of the time, I manage to solve the issue in another way and completely forget to check Stack Overflow.

You should at least acknowledge the attempts of the people who try to assist you. And if their answers don't help then add your own solution so that the question is useful for other people who come across it.
